# why different where condition got the same select results?

Tags: mysql

The confusion as follow:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, let me suggest you to copy and paste your text instead of use an image.

Comment: thanks and could you help me solve my problem? I'm beginner in MySQL

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was about Postgres

Comment: It's barely the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11647710/3270427

Answer (score 4):

This seems to answer your question:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

> Within a string, certain sequences have special meaning unless the
>   NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES SQL mode is enabled. Each of these sequences
>   begins with a backslash (\), known as the escape character. MySQL
>   recognizes the escape sequences shown in Table 10.1, “Special
>   Character Escape Sequences”. For all other escape sequences, backslash
>   is ignored. That is, the escaped character is interpreted as if it was
>   not escaped. For example, \x is just x.

```
Table 10.1 Special Character Escape Sequences
Escape Sequence Character Represented by Sequence
\0  An ASCII NUL (X'00') character
\'  A single quote (') character
\"  A double quote (") character
\b  A backspace character
\n  A newline (linefeed) character
\r  A carriage return character
\t  A tab character
\Z  ASCII 26 (Control+Z); see note following the table
\\  A backslash (\) character
\%  A % character; see note following the table
\_  A _ character; see note following the table
```

eg \i has no special meaning ...